# Overlay an image on top of a video in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a video being displayed on a web page.

A screenshot of the video is taken when the user clicks a button.

I want the user to take the screenshot in a very particular way. Let's say the users are taking screenshots of themselves. I want there to be an overlay that looks like the outline of a headshot type photo. So the user would aim their camera so they fit in to the headshot outline.

What I want to do is provide some sort of overlay on the video. Kind of like the crosshairs on a digital camera are on top of the image.

Ideally, I'd like to make an image with a transparent background, and overlay the image over the video.

Here's a pastebin of the code I'm using currenlty: http://pastebin.com/P8CK38gJ

I'm quite new to HTML5 so please be gentle. Thanks!

Comment: Position:absolute and z-index?

Comment: Doh! That works. For some reason I didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Looks like we have an answer here!